# How can I teach my cat to use the toilet?

Tags: toilet-training

Recently I have adopted a cat from a non-profit organization. It's nearly 2 months old and a little shy. How can I train her to use the toilet instead of urinate on the floor. It's frustrating to clean up. Should I lock it up for a few days? The tool I brought for her is useless.

Comment: What tool? What kind of litter box do you have? Is it small enough that a kitten that young can get into it? And have you taken her to a vet? She is extremely young, and scared of being uprooted and taken away from her family as a baby and thrown into a new place.

Comment: Do you mean a litter box or a "normal" toilet?